# openerp domain filter on a line item property

Tags: odoo

I am trying to filter purchase orders based on a property of its line items. So, for example, I would like to see all purchase orders who have any line item with product_type = 'X'.

```
<record id="po_x" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">X Purchase Orders</field>
        <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
        <field name="res_model">purchase.order</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree,form,calendar,graph,gantt</field>
        <field name="domain">[('has_x_line','=',True)]</field>
        <field name="context">{}</field>
    </record>
```

product_type is a custom field that I added to an inherited version of order line.

```
class purchase_order_custom(osv.osv):
    _name = 'purchase.order'
    _inherit = 'purchase.order'

    def linehasproducttype(self, cr, uid, ids, name, arg, context=None):
        cur_obj={}
        cur_obj=self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context)
        for line in cur_obj.order_line:
            if line.product_type == 'X':
                return True
        return False

    _columns={
          'has_x_line': fields.function(linehasproducttype, string="Has X Line", type='boolean', context={'pt':'X'})
              }
purchase_order_custom()
```

2 questions:

Q1. The above code is not working. That is, it is not really filtering as desired. What could be wrong?

Q2. I have many product types and I am not inclined to make a function for each type. Can I pass an argument somehow or use the context for this purpose as I am trying to do? If so, how do I use it in the code?

Thanks

**EDIT**: I have also tried the following code with no luck:

```
def linehasproducttype(self, cr, uid, ids, name, arg, context=None):
    res = dict.fromkeys(ids, False)
    for cur_obj in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
        res[cur_obj.id] = False
        for line in cur_obj.order_line:
            if line.product_type == 'X':
                res[cur_obj.id] = True
    return res
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have one possibly two problems in your code:

If this code is intended to run on OpenERP 6.1 or prior, you need to provide the argument "method" in your field definition and set it to true, else your method won't be found.

Your function is not generic. It needs to return a dictionary, with the ids given to your function in the "ids" param as keys. You have to remember that almost every function you pass to the OpenERP core needs to work on a set of records and not a single record. Look at the core code for examples.

Regarding your second question, you can always [add data to the context](http://tjhia.wordpress.com/2012/05/18/openerp-5-domain-context/) in your view XML which should then be available in the code handling these views. This will only work if you have distinct views for every product type.

Another possibility would be to define a generic tree view for all products and define a filter, which will only show the desired products. The [developer book describes](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.1/developer/03_modules_3.html#filter-tag) how to do that.

**Edit**: You should be able to just use a domain expression like the following in your action or filter:

```
<field name="domain">[('order_line.product_type','=','X')]</field>
```

Comment: Thanks. 1. I have added method=True in fields.function call for has_x_line. 2. Regarding working on a set of records, is it not the case that self.browse will get me the current record to work with? 3. Can you kindly illustrate returning a dictionary? Will it be a nested for loop? 4. I will have separate views so I can pass the context value from there. But will the code above (has_x_line) to pass context value not work? 5. For another case, I need the generic tree view with filters. Please point to a sample code link for that. Thanks again.

Comment: @RazaAli       See my edit for some more information. Are you sure you are working on v6.1? I don't see the field purchase_order_line.product_type in the source. Did you add it and if you did what is the type of the field? Otherwise your second code example seems to be correct.

Comment: Wow, your simple solution worked!! Thank God. But I am very curious for future usage, why my code didn't work. I am using v7 of openerp and product_type is declared as follows: in a class that inherits purchase.order.line, I declared 'product_type': fields.selection((('X','X'),('Y','Y'),('Z','Z')), 'Product Type', select=True). Thanks for the link.

Comment: @RazaAli       It seems like you are trying to iterate over a field that isn't defined as a list (order_line is a one2many, i.e. it points to a single record). Just check if the linked record has your product_type and put that into your dictionary, without iterating over order_line. Did python/openerp not throw an exception when you executed that code?

Comment: No there was no exception. But if order_line is one2many, that means for every purchase order there are many order lines. So I should be able to iterate over these lines, no?

Comment: Yes you are right, a one2many should return a list you can iterate over. (This always seems to confuse me...) My thought was that domain expressions do not iterate over list values and my example expression shouldn't have worked therefore if order_line was a list. But I've just tested this and they do iterate over list values. I can't help you then, I guess.